# Search two value in one column using MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql

Search two values (Admin, User) in one column (type) and Find Data.

[image]

Comment: Explain your question? what you are trying?

Comment: i have select two word in **type** column. so how to write mysql query

Comment: i have select user and admin data.. seee http://imageshack.com/a/img842/3358/jpo1.jpg

Comment: @Napstar - that doesn't make it any clearer. Can you explain what you're looking for - a SELECT statement that matches rows with either value in the type column?

Comment: SELECT * FROM table WHERE type='user' && type='admin'; but this query is not run imageshack.com/a/img842/3358/jpo1.jpg

Comment: SELECT * FROM table WHERE `type` = 'User' OR `type` = 'Admin'  No way for the Type to be User and Admin!

Comment: What do you want and what have yo tried so far? Maybe you could start with this: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please see my Query below

```
SELECT * FROM Task WHERE type IN("User","Admin");
```

Comment: thax dude :) your query is Run :)

Answer (score 1):

try this query

```
SELECT * FROM Task WHERE type = 'user' || type = 'admin';
```